# How to have a div overlap google maps without using relative/absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, google-maps

A layout I'm trying to build incorporates a google maps embed, with the bottom corner of one div overlapping the top right corner of the google maps.

[Proposed Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yBCn.jpg)
<- Take a look at this image to see the desired layout.

Currently, the google maps div (#div3) overlaps #div2. I need this to be the other way around and a simple z-index change won't fix it. Similar questions on StackOverflow have had a `position: relative` container and `position: absolute` inner div. This solution is unideal for me, as Div 2 isn't meant to be a direct child or related to the google maps, but rather just an unrelated div that appears above the map. I feel like switching to absolute positioning will compromise the layout/potential responsiveness.

**Here's the CSS**

```
#div1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 35%;
    height: 440px;
    float: left;

}

#div2 {

    background-color: green;
    width: 65%;
    float: left;
    height: 670px;
    z-index: 99999999 !important;
}

#div3 {

    width: 55%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -180px;
    z-index: -20;

    #gmap_canvas, #gmap_canvas:after {
        width: 100%;
        height: 620px;
    }

    #gmap_canvas {
        overflow: hidden;
        position:relative;
    }
}

#div4 {
    background-color: pink;
    width: 45%;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
}
```

**And here's a Codepen:**
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzaKME

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please add a codepen or jsfiddle as example of your problem for us to check out.

Comment: @NasirT sure, here it is. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzaKME

Comment: I added my answer. please check and if helped then mark as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, You need to understand how the position and z-index properties work  correctly please check the following links:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Now for an answer to your question. If you have read and understood the position property and the z-index property correctly. You will see that by default the property if not specifically set of an element is set to `position:static` on which z-index does not apply. For z-index to work your `position` property needs to be specifically set to relative/fixed/absolute.

For your solution you need to do the following in your css.

1. Add `position:relative` to your `#div2` class with the z-index as it is.
2. Next though you will see that point 1 fix will get you the desired result but still the `#div3` does not have position specifically set to apply it's z-index just in case. So please add that and also try setting low but positive value of the z-index say `z-index:999;`. We dont want the div to go back down the bottom for any other control to show up above it or hide it if need be.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This gave the desired result without compromising the layout. Didn't know it would be so simple. I also appreciate the clarification on positioning and when I can use the z-index property.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.